# argument in the init method of servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, init

```
public class initCounter extends HttpServlet {
     int count;
     public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config); // purpose of this method ?
        String initial = config.getInitialParameter("initial");
     }
}
```

In the method `init` what does the argument `ServletConfig` indicate ? What it is for ? What does the call `super.init(config)` do ? What is the purpose of this statement ?

I read that the method `getInitialparameter` return the initial paramater, but what is a initial param

Comment: Huh? There is no such method as `getInitialParameter()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletConfig.html By the way, the abbreviation "init" in the method name stands for "initialization", not "initial" which has a very different meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's passed by the container to the servlet in order for the servlet to be able to store it, and call any of its methods.

The purpose of `super.init(config)` is to make sure that, although the method is overridden, the base implementation is nevertheless called.

See [the javadoc of the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29):

> Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being placed into service. See Servlet#init.
>
> This implementation stores the ServletConfig object it receives from the servlet container for later use. When overriding this form of
>   the method, call super.init(config).
>
> Specified by:
>      init in interface Servlet
>
> Parameters:
>      config - the ServletConfig object that contains configutation information for this servlet

An init parameter is a parameter that may be pased to the servlet thanks to the deployment descriptor (web.xml file) of the web app:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>foo</param-name>
    <param-value>bar</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: _"It's passed by the container to the servlet in order for the servlet to be able to store it, and call any of its methods."_  won't i be able to call the servlet methods if don't pass the parameter?

Comment: It's passed by the container, so that the code in the `init(ServletConfig)` method can access the servlet config. This method is not called by your code. It's called **by the container**.

Comment: and what is the need to explicitly call the base implementation ? Can you make this point more clear

Comment: Because if you don't do it, you're not respecting the contract imposed by the javadoc. The base implementation is not called, so the servlet config is not stored, and `getServletConfig()` will thus return null instead of returning the servlet config as it should. This method should not be overridable, but I guess it's a design error that can't be reverted anymore due to the amount of existing code relying on it.

Answer (score 3):

ServletConfig is the config that you configured in your web.xml where the servlet is defined.

e.g.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>redteam</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mysite.server.TeamServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>teamColor</param-name>
        <param-value>red</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>bgColor</param-name>
        <param-value>#CC0000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

getInitParameter("teamColor") would return the String "red" .

super.init(config) will just ensure that your super class is also configured correctly; good practice.

Answer (score 0):

> The argument ServletConfig confg means - the ServletConfig object that
>   contains configutation information for this servlet

read [javaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28%29)

```
init

public void init()
          throws ServletException

    A convenience method which can be overridden so that there's no need to call super.init(config).

    Instead of overriding init(ServletConfig), simply override this method and it will be called by GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig config). The ServletConfig object can still be retrieved via getServletConfig().

    Throws:
        ServletException - if an exception occurs that interrupts the servlet's normal operation
```

also refer [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#init%28javax.servlet.ServletConfig%29)

```
init

public void init(ServletConfig config)
          throws ServletException

    Called by the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is being placed into service. See Servlet.init(javax.servlet.ServletConfig).

    This implementation stores the ServletConfig object it receives from the servlet container for later use. When overriding this form of the method, call super.init(config).

    Specified by:
        init in interface Servlet

    Parameters:
        config - the ServletConfig object that contains configutation information for this servlet
    Throws:
        ServletException - if an exception occurs that interrupts the servlet's normal operation
```

Answer (score 0):

ServletConfig interface represents the init params that you provide for any servlet initialization in "web.xml" file in the  tag.

eg,

topic
some-value

getInitialparameter method returns the value of the init param defined by the input to the method.

Answer (score 0):

the super.init call is to call the init method of GenericServlet ... this does the generic initialization of the servlet.
ServletConfig is the init-param config in web.xml ... e.g.

```
<servlet>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:my.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.me.my.MyServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

would return "classpath:my.xml" for: -

```
config.getInitialParameter("config-location");
```